# How to reuse the same data binding class Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-databinding

I have two similar layout files `item_array_adapter` and `item_recycler_adapter`. The first one has some specific view attributes:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data class="ItemDataBinding">
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.example.myapp.Item" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_text_view"
        android:text="@{item.getName()}"
        //Specific View Attributes />
</layout>
```

And the second one is exactly the same but with other view attributes. The first one is used in an `ArrayAdapter`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
int item = R.layout.item_array_adapter; //Different layout
ItemDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, item , parent, false);
```

And the second is used inside an `RecyclerAdapter`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
int item = R.layout.item_recycler_adapter; //Different layout
ItemDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, item , parent, false);
```

The problem is my app fails with the following message:

> Found data binding error(s):
>   [databinding] {"msg":"Could not write to com.example.myapp.databinding.ItemDataBindingImpl","file":"D:\Projects\MyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\item_array_adapter.xml","pos":[]}

If I use the same layout, it works. So how can I reuse the same `ItemDataBinding` class in both adapters with different layouts?

Comment: By specifying a class name inside your data tags, you're forcing the library to use that name for the generated class. Is it on purpose? Because if you have specified the same name for both layouts, the second one will try to generate a file with the same name and probably fail. I guess that is the reason of your error.
You can reuse a databinding class, but not with different layouts as you are trying to do. Each different layout that specified as databinding layout will have a specific databinding class generated for it.

Comment: @OyaCanlı Thank you so much for commenting to my question. I think you should add it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, done! You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

By specifying a class name inside your data tags like this:

```
<data class="ItemDataBinding">
```

you're forcing the library to use that name for the generated class. Is it on purpose? Because if you have specified the same name for both layouts, the second one will try to generate a file with the same name or override the existing generated file, and probably fail. I guess that is the reason of your error. 
You can reuse a databinding class, but not with different layouts as you are trying to do. Each different layout which is specified as databinding layout(by using layout tags) will generate a seperate binding class.

If you remove the class name from the data tags, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different DataBinding classes generated for each of the layouts, namely, `ItemArrayAdapterbinding` and `ItemRecyclerAdapterbinding`.

You don't see any relation between these two, you certainly cannot use the same Binding class for different layouts.

Comment: There is only a file `ItemDataBinding.java` and one `ItemDataBindingImpl.java`. There are no classes for the adapters. My array adapter class has no specific DataBinding class nor my recycler adapter. What to do?